# A sum involving the Jacobi symbols

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Let $n>1$ be an odd integer and let $(\frac{\cdot}{n})$ be the Jacobi symbol. For an integer $a$, define
$$S_a=\sum_{x=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{x^2-a^2}{n}\right).$$

Are there any results on the explicit value of $S_a$?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want *arbitrary* $a$ or $(a,n)=1$?  If $(a,n)=1$, we can simplify $S_a$. Viewing $S_a$ as a sum over $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ (*not* over the specific set of representatives $0, 1, \ldots, n-1$), the change of variables $x \mapsto ax$ shows $S_a = S_1$ since $(a^2|n) = 1$.  Then $S_1 = (-1|n)\sum_x (x+1|n)(1-x|n)$. Set $x + 1 = 2y$, so $1 - x = 2-2y$ and $S_1 = (-1|n)\sum_y (y|n)(1-y|n)$. That sum over $y$ is a *Jacobi sum* of the Jacobi symbol $(\cdot|n)$ with itself. When $n$ is *prime*, such a sum is $-(-1|n)$: see Theorem 1(c) p. 93 of Ireland and Rosen. So $S_1 = -1$ for prime $n$.

Comment: If you work out numerical examples, you'd see $S_a = -1$ for all $a \not\equiv 0 \bmod n$ when $n$ is prime, which I just explained. Examples show a formula will get complicated for composite $n$ that are not squarefree. It's important to work out lots of examples to get a sense of what might be true, but you did not indicate if you have computed any examples. Using the Chinese remainder theorem, write the sum as a product of such sums where $n$ is an odd prime power, similar to the way Gauss sums of characters mod $n$ are expressible as products of Gauss sums for prime power moduli.